# sql query remove null, empty and only keep matching word

Tags: sql, timeout

I have a list acronyms and matching words

```
acronym | word
---------------
FB      | Facebook
FB      | NULL
FB      | 
T       | Twitter
R       | NULL
F       |
```

If an acronym has a matching word, then list it. If an acronym doesn't have a matching word, then fill the second column with the acronym

E.g: I want to output

```
FB | Facebook
T  | Twitter
R  | R
F  | F
```

I wrote this query which took forever to load, and eventually it timed out. How I am going to accomplish the expected result?

```
select s1.acronym,
        case 
            when s1.acronymnot in  -- acronyms dont have a matching value
                (select s2.acronym
                from myTable s2
                where word is not null and word !='')
                then s1.acronym
            else s1.word
        end as 'word'

    from myTable s1
    where s1.acronym!=''
    and s1.acronymis not null
```

Answer (score 1):

Check Below query, it will help you

```
 SELECT  DISTINCT p.acronym, 
 CASE WHEN ISNULL(q.Word,'') = '' THEN p.acronym ELSE ISNULL(q.Word,'')
 END AS Word
 FROM table1 p LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (SELECT a.acronym ,ISNULL(a.Word,'') Word
 FROM table1 a
 WHERE ISNULL(a.Word,'') <> '') q ON p.acronym = q.acronym
```

Comment: thanks. the problem with this is that there is duplicate acronym. E.g: ... FB | FB, FB | Facebook, ... I think the data is too bad. What is the best way remove the duplication?

Comment: first you identify what record you want FB or Facebook ? then you need some global logic for removing extra record in your query result.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
    accronym varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT accronym FROM accro
WHERE name is not null AND name != ''

SELECT accronym, name
FROM accro as tmp
WHERE name is not null AND name != ''
UNION
SELECT accronym, 
    CASE 
        WHEN name IS NULL OR name = ''
        THEN accronym
        ELSE name
    END
FROM accro
WHERE (name is null OR name = '') AND accronym NOT IN (SELECT accronym FROM @temp)
```